# How to catch 'FatalExecutionEngineError' in C#?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, fatal-error, gdal

I am experimenting a tedious problem with a C# routine that I cannot to solve. I am developing an application that opens a ESRI ShapeFile using the GDAL library (an DLL library written in C++ to manipulate geographical data) and shows the map in a PictureBox component. When I use a vector of System.Drawing.Point objects to draw the polygons I get the following message:

**Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users\polli\ipeageo-git\IpeaGEO\bin\Debug\IpeaGEO.vshost.exe'.
Additional information: The runtime found a fatal error. The error address is 0x6ced9a0f, in thread 0x1618. The error code is 0xc0000005.**

This is the code that throws the exception:

```
private void drawGeometry(Geometry geo, Graphics g, bool fill)
{
    // Some code here...
    // ...

    // Get the points count and the array to ask GDAL for coordinates.
    int count = geo.GetPointCount();
    double[] v = new double[2];
    Point[] polygon = new Point[count];

    for (int pid = 0; pid < count; pid++)
    {
        geo.GetPoint(pid, v);    // This is a call to GDAL (unmanaged) code.
        polygon[pid].X = getX((float)v[0]);
        polygon[pid].Y = getY((float)v[1]);

        // The Exception occurs just HERE!
        g.DrawPolygon(fgPen, polygon); // <--- EXCEPTION!!!
        if (fill) g.FillPolygon(fillBrush, polygon);
    }

    // Some code here...
    // ...
}
```

I have another version of this function that works fine, where I am drawing each line segment without allocating memory:

```
private void drawGeometry(Geometry geo, Graphics g, bool fill)
{
    // Some code here...
    // ...

    Point start = new Point(), current = new Point(), previous = new Point();

    // Get the points count and the array to ask GDAL for coordinates.
    int count = geo.GetPointCount();
    double[] v = new double[2];

    for (int pid = 0; pid < count; pid++)
    {
        geo.GetPoint(pid, v);    // This is a call to GDAL (unmanaged) code.
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            start.X = previous.X = getX((float)v[0]);
            start.Y = previous.Y = getY((float)v[1]);
         } // if
         else
         {
             previous.X = current.X;
             previous.Y = current.Y;
         } // else

         current.X = getX((float)v[0]); current.Y = getY((float)v[1]);
         g.DrawLine(fgPen, previous.X, previous.Y, current.X, current.Y);
    } // for
    g.DrawLine(fgPen, start.X, start.Y, current.X, current.Y);

    // Some code here...
    // ...
}
```

I need to fill some polygons and I cannot to do it with the second version of the code (that is working fine). The use of **try ... catch** does not capture the exception.

I think the problem occurs when the **garbage collector** is running in the background and I try to access the polygon variable (that is a vector of about 2000 elements... and this code is inside a **for** statement).

Anybody knows how to catch (or, even better, avoid) this kind of exception?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the name of that exception. The reason it is called "fatal" is because it is, there's no hope to continue executing in the process, it is doomed. Your only solution would be to figure out *why* it happens, and fix that, but you cannot catch it.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot avoid the Exception to occur. I need to find a way to avoid the competition with the garbage collector. The trouble occurs when I access the __polygon__ vector (I think it may be locked by the garbage collector).

Comment: I don't think it's a GC problem. My guess; your C++ library requires `geo.GetPoint(pid, **ref** v);` But you have the change the declaration of `GetPoint` for this (in your wrapper code, (if it's not yours you are in trouble))...

Comment: You should show the declaration in the dll as well as how you declared it in C#.

Comment: And the problem is that you **must** avoid it because you simply cannot catch and handle that exception. Something went so horribly wrong that the process will be terminated, there's no way around this. So you need to figure out how to avoid the exception in the first place.

Comment: I think this may be one possible solution. But, I use the same function in the other code that is working!

Comment: @EZI: I think to have found the solution (based in the information by EZI that it would be a problem with the vector returned by GeoPoint). The function  returns a vector of 3 positions (x, y, z) and I was allocating only 2 positions (x, y). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**FatalExecutionEngineError** are not catchable in exception handling, they are usually system bugs or marshal errors, both can't be handled in .NET app.